# How can you access a rocket(rust) state at the end of the servers life?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I want to be able to do something with my state once the server starts shutting down

example:

```rs
struct MyConfig {
    user_val: String
}

#[get("/hello")]
fn hello(config: &State<MyConfig>) -> Result<String, error::Error> {
    //do stuff
    Ok(&config.user_val)
}

#[rocket::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), error::Error> {
    let config = MyConfig{user_val: "hello".to_string()};
    let _rocket = rocket::build()
        .manage(config) //cant pass as borrow because it wont live long enough
        .mount("/", routes![hello])
        .launch()
        .await?;


    println!("{}", &config.user_val); //cant access because value moved

    Ok(())
}
```

The result should be when I shut down the program it prints user_val(I dont want to clone)

but after setting it as a state its no longer accessible after the server ends

Comment: You should be able to access a `&MyConfig` via `_rocket.state::<MyConfig>().unwrap()` after `_rocket` completes successfully (that is, graceful shutdown). AFAICS there is no way to retrieve an owned version, but you could wrap `MyConfig` into an `Arc` and `Arc::into_inner()` if you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 2):

You can get access to the config by using `.state()` afterwards:

```
struct MyConfig {
    user_val: String,
}

#[rocket::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), rocket::error::Error> {
    let config = MyConfig { user_val: "hello".to_string()};
    let rocket = rocket::build()
        .manage(config)
        .ignite() // this puts it in the post-launch state for testing
        .await?;

    let config = rocket.state::<MyConfig>().unwrap();

    println!("{}", config.user_val);

    Ok(())
}
```

```
hello
```

Although, `config` will be a *reference*. You aren't able to take ownership back after giving it to Rocket. If you need ownership, you'll have to `.clone()` the config or store it in an `Arc` before managing so you can `.clone()` that to avoid duplicating the underlying config data.